# Curl error 6: Curl Can't resolve host name

Tags: php, curl, youtube, guzzle, codeigniter-3

I need your help regarding `curl` error. I am using `youtube api` for accessing `youtube videos` and other contents. I have developed a basic site for it.

It was working perfectly before today. Today i tried to access my site from browser and get this error.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException

Message: cURL error 6: See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

I'am confused now what did do that. It is perfectly working fine when i echo some thing before a `youtube api` call. below is the code.

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client -> setDeveloperKey('XXXXX');
    $client->setClientId('XXXX');
    $client->setClientSecret('XXXXXX');


$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$youtube -> search -> listSearch('id,snippet', array('safeSearch' => 'strict', 'q' => $q, 'order' => $order, 'maxResults' => $maxResults, 'type' => 'video', 'videoDuration' => 'any'));
```

before the listSearch call every thing works perfectly but this is the line when it executes it cause this error. Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: Error means: "Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved." How do you set remote host in your code?

Comment: i am a starter and i am using codeigniter framework. can you explain me where can i find it what you are asking for. i dont know much about hosting it is my first site. thanks

Comment: I have just read error number from link you provided. Are you using latest API code?

Comment: yes i am using v3 api and latest php client library